# Gridview findcontrol after dropdownlist event

Tags: asp.net

I want to findcontrol on griview after DDL OnSelectedIndexChanged event. where the target control is on the rowindex where the DDL is located..

here my codes;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList Dummysource = new ArrayList() { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };

    if(!IsPostBack )
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Dummysource;
        GridView1.DataBind();  
    }

}

protected void ddlsample_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string valueComponent = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;


    Label1.Text = valueComponent;

}


int ddlvalue;
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Checking whether the Row is Data Row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Finding the Dropdown control.
        DropDownList ddlsample = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlsample");
        Label ilbldata = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbldata");

        if (ddlsample != null)
        {
            switch(ilbldata.Text) 
            {

                case "AA":
                    ddlvalue = 2;
                    break;
                case "BB":
                    ddlvalue = 3;
                    break;
                case "CC":
                    ddlvalue = 4;
                    break;
                case "DD":
                    ddlvalue = 5;
                    break;  

            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= ddlvalue; i++ )
            {
                ddlsample.Items.Add(i.ToString() );   
            }
        }
    }

}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;
    gv = GridView1; 
    Label  foo = gv.SelectedRow.FindControl("lbldata") as Label ;
    Label2.Text = foo.Text;  
}
```

the code get the value of the DropDownList selected Item. I'm Wondering on how to get the component value in the gridview. after selectedindexchange event of DDL

I made some visual photo for more clear
http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b493/Kasparov1/GridviewDDL_zps3721fb97.png

thanks in advance;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void ddlsample_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

    Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Value;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

   // Find your control
   Control control = row.FindControl("myControl");
}
```

Comment: got it sir thanks                                                         protected void ddlsample_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valueComponent = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
        Label1.Text = valueComponent;

        DropDownList  ddl = (sender as DropDownList);

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

        // Find your control
       Label  control = row.FindControl("lbldata") as Label ;
        Label2.Text = control.Text ;  

    }

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList drop = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
   string text = drop.Items[drop.SelectedIndex].ToString();
   //Find FooterRow Control
   DropDownList dT = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
   string text = dT.Items[dT.SelectedIndex].ToString();
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//DropDownList1 in GridVied 
{
    //Find FooterRow Control
    DropDownList drop = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    string text = drop.Items[drop.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    //find normal DropDownList1
    DropDownList drop1 = GridView1.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    string text = drop1.Items[drop1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
 }

//ADD list in GRIDVIEW dropdownlist at run time

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");//Gridview DropDownList
   ddl.Items.Add("- - Select - -");
   ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("ABCD"));
   ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("EFGH"));
}
```